# How write from string numbers to array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

```
string line = "1    2 3  4          5";
```

how write this numbers to array ?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include example code showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `stringstream`;

for example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    std::string line="1    2 3  4          5";
    int n;
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::stringstream s(line);
    while(s>>n){
      v.push_back(n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Error] invalid use of template-name 'std::vector' without an argument list

Comment: [Error] variable 'std::stringstream s' has initializer but incomplete type

Comment: I've change the code to full working program.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

string line = "1    2 3  4          5";
vector<int> nums;

for(char i : line) {
  if(isspace(i)) {
    continue;
  }
  else {
    nums.push_back((int) i - 48);
  }
}
```

Comment: so you are casting the char `'1'` to an `int` that would give and integer with the value 49. I don't think that what the question is asking for. . .

Comment: [Error] range-based 'for' loops are not allowed in C++98 mode

Comment: @tagi-asadullazadeh sorry but I usually solve c++ problems in c++11

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int convert(char *input, int **v)
{
 if (input==NULL)
 {
 printf("The string is NULL");
 return 0;
 }
 else
 { 
  if ((*v)==NULL)
 { 
 unsigned int count=0;
 for (int i=0;input[i]!='\0';i++)
     if (isdigit(input[i]))
              count++;
     (*v)=(int*)malloc(count*sizeof(int));
 }
 char aux[2]={'\0','\0'};
 unsigned int count=0;
 for (int i=0;input[i]!='\0';i++)
  if (isdigit(input[i]))
   {
    aux[0]=input[i];
    (*v)[count]=atoi(aux);
    count++
   }
 }
}
```

Next time you should try to come with a solution yourself and show it to us before asking.